# Real interpolation of $L^p_xL^q_y$-space

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I want to know if the following holds:

Given $2<p<q_1<q<q_2<\infty$ s.t. $1/q_1+1/q_2=2/q$,

$$(L^p_xL^{q_1}_y,L^p_xL^{q_2}_y)_{1/2,2}\subset L^p_xL^q_y\,\,\,?$$

Here, $L^p_xL^q_y$ denotes the mixed norm space $L^p(\mathbb{R};L^q(\mathbb{R}))$, and the notation $(\cdot,\cdot)_{\theta,\eta}$ denotes the real interpolation space.

---

/What I know is that when $p=2$, we know something even better:
$$(L^2_xL^{q_1}_y,L^2_xL^{q_2}_y)_{1/2,2}=L^2_xL^{q,2}_y$$ (the Lorentz space) under the same setting (Sections 1.18.2 and 1.18.6 of Interpolation Theory, Function Spaces, Differential Operators by Triebel), so I expect this to be true, but I don't have any idea to prove this at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean $(,)_{1/2,2}$ since $\theta\in(0,1)$ ...

I am not sure I understand your problem but a way to prove that is to use the fact that
$$
(L^p(A_0),L^p(A_1))_{\theta,2} = L^p((A_0,A_1)_{\theta,2}),
$$
as indicated for example in the book you mention in Section 1.18.4. Hence with $θ = 1/2$,
$$
(L^p_xL^{q_1}_y,L^p_xL^{q_2}_y)_{θ,2} = L^p((L^{q_1},L^{q_2})_{θ,2}) = L^p(L^{q,2}) ⊂ L^p_xL_y^{q}
$$
since $q>2$.